# The limit of powers of a radon matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}, 0<a_{ij}<1$, $e=(1,\cdots,1)'$, $Ae=e, A' e=e$. 试证: $\lim_{k\to\infty}A^k=\frac{1}{n}ee'$.

If all the eigenvalues of $A$ has absolute value $<1$, then $A^k\to 0$. But what about this problem?

Comment: If the matrix is double stochastic (i.e. sum of rows is 1 and sum of columns is 1) then its power is also double stochastic. Hence the limit of $A^k$ can not be $0$.

Comment: @Salcio then how to prove $A^k\to \frac{1}{n}ee'$?